# Clojure: express failed computation as value for core.async

Tags: error-handling, clojure, core.async

Usually functions that may fail return `nil`: `some->` macro is designed to chain computations like that (looks like that  "M" word). The question is how to use this approach with core.async, like park for heavy `async/thread` computation which can fail and cannot return `nil` because of channels restriction on this. Is `{:right/:left}` maps idiomatic? Any good practices that you use?

Comment: You mean you take a value off the chan, and want to react to whether or not the taken value represents a failed action? If you don't need to handle a failure, you could just not put in the first place. I seem to recall in a toy project declaring a namespaced keyword, and checking against that when taking. That single keyword represented failure, and was namespaced to prevent accidental false positives. Left/right isn't really an idiom in Clojure, or at least not one I've come across in my couple years dealing with it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate i have to handle the failure. So, keywords, as usual

Comment: Yes. Keywords are the hammer for many problems, for better or worse.

Comment: A fun, useful exercise might be creating a `->while-not` macro that threads the expressions while the return value of the forms *isn't* a certain value. It would be like a generalized `some->`. You could redefine `some->` using it with something like ``(defmacro some-> [expr & forms] `(->while-not nil ~expr ~@forms))``

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this using the `with-exception-default` macro [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#default-value-in-case-of-exception).  It allows you to replace an exception with any arbitrary value, which could be a "sentinal" value to indicate (in a non-exception way) that a failure occurred (such as putting a keyword on a core.async channel):

```
  (let [good (with-exception-default :failed (+ 2 3))
        bad  (with-exception-default :failed (/ 2 0)) ] ... )

good => 5
bad  => :failed
```

Another approach is to just wrap regular thread `->` with a test:

```
(or (-> ...<forms>...)  ; assumes `false` cannot be a result
  :failed)
```

Comment: The first approach looks hacky a bit, because the failed computation is not exceptional. Could you explain your second approach? How it is related with value returned from channel?

Comment: The result of the `(or (-> ...) :failed)` is what you would put on the channel. If `<forms>` returns `nil`, the `or` will "fall through" and return the `:failed` keyword.